# How long did it take the spaceship to travel

Tags: grammar

Which is a correct sentence with for or without for?

"How long did it take (for) the spaceship to travel from Florida to the ISS?"

"The trip took (for) the spaceship 19 hours."

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody answers, I would like to answer even though I am not a native speaker.

Your first

> "How long did it take (for) the spaceship to travel from Florida to the ISS?"

is correct. This is the [**case 13 of the preposition of "for" explained here.**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/for)

> used after some adjectives, nouns, and verbs for saying who or what does the action of the following verb

> **for someone/something to do something**: It was difficult **for** me **to** understand what he was saying.

> All I want is **for** you **to** be happy.

> It is time **for** Congress **to** begin exploring some new approaches.

---

Your next sentence has a problem of the position of the preposition of "for".

That is not

> "The trip took (for) the spaceship 19 hours."

But instead

> "The trip took the spaceship **for** 19 hours."

since it is used to denote "**used for saying how long something lasts or continues**",[**the definition of 3a of the preposition of the "for" explained there.**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/for)

> **used for saying how long something lasts or continues**

> There have been drought conditions **for** the last two summers.

> I’ve been waiting **for** 20 minutes.